# How to exclude few images from docker image prune command?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

I have below images on my server.

`myrepo/oneimage:tag1`

`myrepo/oneimage:tag2`

`myrepo/secondimage:tag`

`myrepo/thirdimage:tag`

I'm running command `docker image prune -a -f` to clean up all docker images on a server. But I want the command to not remove couple of images. So I added a label to the images as `LABEL imagename="myimage"` to `myrepo/oneimage:tag1` and `myrepo/oneimage:tag2`. I modified prune command as below, but it is not working as I want.

`docker image prune -f --filter label!=imagename="myimage"` - Doesn't remove any images

`docker image prune -f --filter="label!=imagename=myimage"` - Doesn't remove any images

`docker image prune -a -f --filter="label!=imagename=myimage"` - Removes all images including the image with label `imagename="myimage"`

How can I remove all the images except `myrepo/oneimage:tag1` and `myrepo/oneimage:tag2` using docker image prune?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a | grep -v $(docker images myrepo/oneimage:tag1 | awk 'NR>1 {print $3}') | grep -v $(docker images myrepo/oneimage:tag2 | awk 'NR>1 {print $3}') | awk 'NR>1 {print $3}')
```

Explain:

- The command above will list and remove all images by their ID except the 2 images you need retain.

In addition, you can't add a `lable` to an existing image. It must be added during image creation.